# Getting crontab to run rebuild

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I'm building a script which helps me to re-build static sites every day when new content is updated on my CMS. For testing purposes, I'm trying it out on my local computer.

The script named helloworld.sh is

`#!/bin/bash
(cd /Projects/blog && gatsby build)`

And I have edited crontab -e to that of

`* * * * * /Projects/scripts/helloworld.sh`

which gets it to run each minute just for testing purposes. However, it is not working and returns an error, No MTA installed, discarding output when I run service cron status. Which I looked up and it is regarding mailing output and that it supposedly should not affect what the script does at all.

```
Apr 30 23:05:01 unicornfinder CRON[12363]: (unicornfinder) CMD (/Projects/scripts/helloworld.sh)

Apr 30 23:05:01 unicornfinder CRON[12362]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

How would I get this script to run? Thanks!

Comment: The parentheses in the shell script are superfluous and inefficient, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

When there's an error on cron jobs and job output is not redirected to a file, cron tries to send an email to the user which in your case fails because there's no **MTA**. Edit your crontab

`* * * * * /Projects/scripts/helloworld.sh >> /tmp/file.log 2>&1`

Comment: Not just an error. It tries to mail any output of the script.

Comment: You need to put `>> /tmp/file.log` first.